# javascript - match defined tags present in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, tags, match

I defined some tags in an array:

```
var myArray = [
    "mouse",
    "common",
    "malcom",
    "mountain",
    "melon",
    "table"
];
```

Now I want to extract my defined tags from a string, for example

from the string: `the mouse is on the desk`, I want to extract the **"mouse"** tag

or from the string `the mouse is on the table`, I want to extract the tags **"mouse"** and **"table"**

This code partially works, but there is some problem:

```
var myArray = [
    "mouse",
    "common",
    "malcom",
    "mountain",
    "melon",
    "table"
];

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "MatchInArray", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(value) {
        return this.filter(function(currentItem) {
            return currentItem.match(value);
        });
    }
});

function doSearch(text){
    out = myArray.filter(function(currentItem){
        return currentItem.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1;
    });
    return out;
}

myInput.oninput = function(){
    var XXX = this.value;
    var YYY = XXX.replace(/ /g,',');
    var ZZZ = YYY.split(',');
    for(var i=0; i<ZZZ.length; i++){
        output.innerHTML = doSearch(ZZZ[i]);
    }
    //output.innerHTML = doSearch(this.value);
};
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/27neq4jr/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the comparison of text to item so that you don't have to do all that regex and splitting:

```
function doSearch(text){
    out = myArray.filter(function(currentItem){
        return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(currentItem) !== -1;
    });
    return out;
}

myInput.oninput = function(){
    output.innerHTML = doSearch(this.value);
};
```

Comment: I noticed that in this way, partial words do not longer match tags... I need to match tags also with partial words! Please help

Comment: So for `the mouse is on the desk` you want `mouse,common,melon`?

Comment: For example, If I just type "o", now I have no results.. but before, all words containing "o" were shown

Comment: yeah, I was just pointing out that it goes against your original requirements

Comment: Is there no way to solve it? I really need to match tags also with partial words.. I hope there is a solution..

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of ways to solve it. I was just debating whether to tell you, since I don't that is the point of SO. http://jsfiddle.net/27neq4jr/2/